# What sort of Q&A does this "Meta Stack Overflow" deal with?

Tags: support, meta, discussion

As a new user, may I ask what kind of Q&A and discussions this "Meta Stack Overflow" deals with?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-work and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Answer (score 2):

[The definitive SO Blog post about Meta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/)

Basically Meta is for bug reports, feature requests and talk *about* the Trilogy and Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Also, reading the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) doesn't hurt.