# What is Meta Stack Overflow really?

Tags: discussion, support, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What sort of Q&A does this "Meta Stack Overflow" deal with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56097)

This question is not a re-post. I have tried to look for exactly what is Meta Stack Overflow. This is my question. What I understand about Meta Stack Overflow is that any query or suggestion regarding Stack Overflow website can be asked here.
Is that true?

And if yes, then how can I contribute?
What exactly is the point of having such a website when things are only managed by the do-ers of the Stack Overflow website?
Please enlighten me...

As per few comments I received, this is a part of the FAQ. I am not a time waster who wouldn't read FAQ before posting a question. My question put in order words is: Say I have an issue with Stack Overflow, and I need to report that. And I reported it on Meta Stack Overflow. Who would fix the bug? Of course, the team of Stack Overflow. Right? So does it mean, they all are on Meta Stack Overflow, frequently looking for bugs and suggestions?

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: As with all things just...poke around. See what people post, what people ask and see what you can help with or what sort of questions you could ask.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Yes, Stack Exchange employees and Stack Overflow moderators monitor Meta Stack Overflow routinely.

Comment: the URL http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/ gave me the exact answer. Thanks guyz

Comment: The blog link gave me the answer I was looking for which the FAQ did not. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Perhaps the more accurate question would have been why do we have meta-stackoverflow. But the point is that while the FAQ first section may answer the what question, it does not get to the WHY question which the blog post succinctly does. Perhaps the MODS will simply put the blog link in the FAQ and we can all be happy.

Answer (score 1):

It is one of the QA sites on Stack Exchange network, where you can ask questions about:

- Stack Overflow
- Stack Exchange
- Stack Overflow Careers
- Promotions & Advertising
- Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites

That is [first section on the FAQ page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) of meta.

Comment: so why cant i have an option of "SUPPORT" on each website. Hasn't this the tradition of almost every website online? sorry, i am just being dumb.

Comment: @Athar: meta _is_ that thing you're talking about (and a bit more).

Comment: what exactly is different and why? thats what i wanna know @MAT

Comment: See the post (and its answer) I linked to in the comments to your question, @Athar.