# What kind of question I could post in this website?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What sort of Q&A does this “Meta SO” deal with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56097/what-sort-of-qa-does-this-meta-so-deal-with)

I just click the link from website Stackoverflow.com and it show me this website. But This website is the same style and flow as Stackoverflow.com.

Why I need this website? Why don't we use only stackoverflow?

Comment: Have you already read the [faq]?

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow has a [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), same as with Stack Overflow. Please read it thoroughly.

Comment: thanks RobW and Yannis Rozos

Comment: I just post a question and they just downvote my first question :(

Comment: Right *there* next to the textarea for asking a new question it says: "Is your question about Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange network?"

Comment: @Kannika Don't take downvotes personally. The fact is, each site within the SO/SE network has a FAQ page linked at the very top of the site. This is the page you have been linked to within the answers and comments. There you can find what each site is about and what kind of questions you should ask. Given that this is so obvious (to many of us) you might have simply received some downvotes because you didn't search enough. Reputation on Meta doesn't mean a whole lot anyway and you've learned something new.

Comment: @Bart It's just my experience that i got it. But look like i won't post that kind of this question again. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Just see the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) about this site. You can ask any question about StackOverflow. You can ask questions related to bugs, feature request, or support for StackOverflow.